# Exists, or Within

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm writing a some filtering logic that basically wants to first check if there's a value in the filter table, then if there is return the filtered values. When there isn't a value in the filter table just return everything. The following table does this correctly but I have to write the same select statement twice.

```
select *
  from personTbl
 where (not exists (select filterValue from filterTable where filterType = 'name') or
        personTbl.name in (select filterValue from filterTable where filterType = 'name'))
```

Is there some better way to do this that will return true if the table is empty, or the value is contained within it?

Comment: I cannot think of a better way. You can use a WITH clause, though, in order to have to write the subquery just once.

Comment: That's my answer as well - use the WITH clause (query subfactoring) so if you ever need to make changes to the subquery code, you can make them just once (ease of maintenance, not just of writing it the first time).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to do a left outer join to your filter-subquery, and then select all the rows where the join either failed (meaning that the subquery returned no rows) or succeeded *and* had the right value:

```
SELECT personTbl.*
  FROM personTbl
  LEFT
 OUTER
  JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT filterValue
           FROM filterTable
          WHERE filterType = 'name'
       ) filter
    ON 1 = 1
 WHERE filter.filterValue = personTbl.name
    OR filter.filterValue IS NULL
;
```

To be honest, I'm not sure if the above is a good idea — it's not very intuitive<sup>1</sup>, and I'm not sure how well it will perform — but you can judge for yourself.

---

*1. As evidence of its unintuitiveness, witness the mistaken claim below that it doesn't work. As of this writing, that comment has garnered two upvotes. So although the query is correct, it clearly inspires people to great confidence that it's wrong. Which is a nice party trick, but not generally desirable in production code.*

Comment: This answer is incorrect. To start with, this is no outer join. `1=1` is always true, so you can make this an inner join with the WHERE clause becoming part of the ON clause. We can also assume there are no NULL entries for filterValue in the table, so you can remove `OR filter.filterValue IS NULL`. The whole query thus always gets all names in the filter, if there are none you get no records.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner There can be a `NULL` value from the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` if there are no entries in the `filter` table.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: I'm sorry, but your entire comment is wrong from start to finish. You can see the no-records-in-filter behavior at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d7329/1. (Note: that SQL Fiddle uses MySQL rather than Oracle, because Oracle no longer works at sqlfiddle.com; but if you have an Oracle installation handy, you can try it out for yourself.)

Comment: @ruakh: I apologize. You are right. Seems a good time to go to bed :-|

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: No worries. It really is a very unintuitive query. Your WITH-clause suggestion is much better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a collection to try to make the query more intuitive (and only require a single select from the filter table):

```
CREATE TYPE filterlist IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
/

SELECT p.*
FROM   PersonTbl p
       INNER JOIN
       ( SELECT CAST(
                  MULTISET(
                    SELECT filterValue
                    FROM   filterTable
                    WHERE  filterType = 'name'
                  )
                  AS filterlist
                ) AS filters
         FROM   DUAL ) f
       ON ( f.filters IS EMPTY OR p.name MEMBER OF f.filters );
```